# how do i combine 4 sets of 0 and 1 in php with all the possible combinations of 4 digits?

Tags: php, math

My question is very simple how do i combine 4 sets of 0 and 1 in all 4 digits combinations, with a simple algorythm in php? Example below:

```
0000, 1111, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1100, 0011, 0101, 0110, 1110, 1101, 1011, 0111
```

Comment: please show what you've already tried

Comment: i have nothing in my hands, i'm looking for an elegant code, if someone can help...

Comment: You can do a foreach from 0 to 15 and convert to binary on every iteration.

Comment: This should be the code:

    for($n = 1; $n <= 16; $n++){
       echo decbin($n) . ", ";
    }

and this is the output:
1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111, 10000

this is not what i need though, but you gave a great idea to realize something else, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant, but it'll get the job done.

```
<?php
foreach (array(0, 1) as $i) {
        foreach (array(0, 1) as $j) {
                foreach (array(0, 1) as $k) {
                        foreach (array(0, 1) as $l) {
                                echo "$i$j$k$l\n";
                        }
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are just the binary representations of the numbers 0 to 15 using 4 digits. You can use `sprintf` to format a number in such a binary representation:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
    $res[] = sprintf("%04b", $i);
}
```

The `$res` array will have the values you expect.